# systemd unit file to run bash command with terminal input

Tags: systemd

I have the following unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup Thing

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash
StandardInput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/pts/19
```

What I am trying to do is pipe input from a terminal to /bin/bash. But for some reason the terminal kind of doesn't process my input correctly. When I type "ls", the terminal only shows the "l" and no "s"... this happens to all other commands as well. What am I doing wrong?